# I want to extract a string before and after a specific occurence of a specific character in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which is having data like this :

```
/hey[my]/file/exec[jhwwdfbfjuneinfcvdkvnkdvn]
```

I want to write a sql query to fetch only "file" from this column.
I want to trim the string after the 3rd occurence of '/' character and before the 2nd occurence of '/' character. File string is dynamic, for every record the file name is different so can't use like.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('/', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('/', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col))) - 1);
```

Result - `LINE 1: SELECT SUBSTRING(s.value, LEN(LEFT(s.value, charindex ('/', ...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

datatype of s.value is text.
I am applying this query in postgresql database.

I don't know how to give the occurences in sql query.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You can use `explode()` in php

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Copy the full error message: there are 3 CHARINDEX and we don't even know what error you get. Error messages often tell what is the error and exactly where it happens.

Comment: You can use Like operator for just checking that text contains file string, simply use like operator.

Comment: What if the type of the column s.value?

Comment: dataType of s.value  is text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one thing split that string into array by split string and take interval that you want in you case it would be 3rd interval i guess.

So here is the simple example

```
SELECt split_part(FirstName, '/', 3)) As firstindex,firstname from Persons_details;
```

Try this syntax and let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: ERROR:  function substring_index(text, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select trim(substring_index(s.value,'/',3)) as details ,r.ho...
                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Why you putting unknown? what is your column name?

Comment: column name is s.value

Comment: Then use like substring_index(columnname, '/', 3)

Comment: ERROR:  function substring_index(text, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select (substring_index(s.value, '/', 3)) as details ,r.host...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Are you using mysql or mssql?

Comment: postgresql database. But i thought it will support all the mysql queries but actually its not

Comment: Then use this function split_part(s.value, '/', 3) this should work and try to check same function.

Comment: Your welcome. you can mark answer correct then ;) if it works fine.